# SQLite 'INSERT INTO' Error - Populate new table

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, insert-into

I searched the hinted posts, when posting this question but I foud none similar, so I apologize if I missed any.

Here's my problem. I created a table and it's fields, in SQLite Administrator, then I wrote the following query to populate the table:

```
  USE Contact_Database;

  INSERT into Names (Contact_ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES
  (1, 'Joana', 'Tavares'),
  (2, 'Patrícia', 'Dias'),
  (3, 'Paulo', 'Costa'),
  (4, 'Marco', 'Almeida'),
  (5, 'Bruno', 'Lindo'),
  (6, 'Manuela', 'Lindo'),
  (7, 'João', 'Lindo'),
  (8, 'Rui', 'Trindade');
```

Result error: SQL Error: near "USE": syntax error

I've also tried with:

```
  INSERT into Contact_Database.Names
```

Result error: SQL Error: near ",": syntax error  <

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't do multiline inserts, AFAIK. You need a separate insert for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple inserts in one query are not supported.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) for more information.

Comment: Thank You!! It worked with the UNION SELECT!

Comment: The same is now happening but with creating a table...

                                               
    CREATE TABLE [Names] (
   [Contact_ID] INTEGER DEFAULT 'None' NOT NULL PRIMARY  KEY          
    AUTOINCREMENT,
   [FirstName] CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'NULL' NULL,
   [LastName] CHAR(20) DEFAULT 'NULL' NULL
    )

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but I solved it while I ignore (delete) the insertion query during creating table.

I changed this

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MessageTable VALUES(datetime(),'Pir Fahim',00923359110795','Hello,testing');");
```

to:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CallTable VALUES('"+call_time+"','"+name+"','"+phone_no+"','"+interface_style+"','"+tone+"','"+voice_path+"','"+vibration_mode+"');");
```